# Schematic Infrared Break Line Alarm Receiver

Tags: infrared

Can anyone help me with the attached schematic, I don't really understand were the line of " VREF" connects to , maybe I can not see the trees for the forest!

9v

cheers

spike[image: Velleman MK 120]
Hi

Thank you all , for all your replies, I have tried to do a schematic that I can understand from the schematic I first put on here, would anyone be able to have the time and patience to check it out!

Cheers and again thanks, what a great site, and nice people willing to help people like me that are very new to electronics.

spike

[image]

Comment: I am not a school child , I don't need anyone changing or altering my wording .

Answer (score 1):

Vref is generated by IC1D, and it serves as a DC bias for all other stages, so they can work with ac coupled signals.

Comment: Thanks for that info , do I take it that 14 , 3 , and 5 of the IC LM324 are linked together ! , and were does COMP link to ! , sorry for all the questions I am just a newbie .chhers  spike

Comment: No problem, yes you should take it as an internal connection, it is just to avoid having a wire line going all through the schematic. Comp goes from C3 to the inverting input of IC1C, which is acting as a comparator.

Comment: Thanks all ,  for your replies , there is just one more problem with this schemtic , that is the time period when activating the alarm is very short , is there a way of increasing the time on to the alarm ! .cheers  spike

Comment: I would say increasing C3 value should give a longer time to detection. But I'm not sure how much time you are thinking about, you could require something different.

Comment: Hi , thanks for your reply , I am wanting to replace the Buzzer with a relay hopefully  ( not sure of the current to the buzzer )  , so I would of thought about 3 seconds , I think this circuit is quite short maybe 1 second ! .cheers  spike